# MYSQL difference between/gap rows having the same id and count the difference/gap

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My target is how can I count the difference/gap before the userID appears again on the table?

[image]

**This is my table (testing.tbl)**

| UserID | Name | Datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sport | 2021-10-15 13:00:01 |
| 2 | it | 2021-10-15 13:01:02 |
| 3 | game | 2021-10-15 13:01:31 |
| 1 | sport | 2021-10-15 13:01:50 |
| 1 | game | 2021-10-15 13:02:01 |
| 3 | it | 2021-10-15 13:03:54 |
| 3 | sport | 2021-10-15 13:04:05 |
| 2 | it | 2021-10-15 13:05:00 |

This is their difference count. These results happen because I counted the difference before they appeared in the table again.

**My target result**:

| userID | Difference | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 |  |
| 3 | 2 | 0 |

Comment: Do you have any datetime or something to sort your testing table?? Because if you don't, there is no way that you can get the gap because the table is never ordered and the gap could be different every time you query it

Comment: Hello, thank you for commenting. I added Datetime. Please, see the edited post. Thank you